# How to retrieve datetime (datetype only) from access 2007 database using vb.net 2010?

Tags: vb.net, datetime

**My requirement is to let user pick a date from DateTimePicker and a GataGridView will then retrieves and shows the info(s) where match to the value from DateTimePicker.**

```
 Private Sub DateTimePicker3_ValueChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles DateTimePicker3.ValueChanged
    dailyloadglog()
End Sub
```

.

```
Public Sub dailyloadglog()
    Dim connection As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" & aaa & "';Persist Security Info=True;")
    Try
        Dim OOL As String = "SELECT Glogtbl.DIN, Glogtbl.clock, Int([clock]) AS JustDate, [clock]-Int([clock]) AS JustTime FROM Glogtbl WHERE JustDate = " & DateTimePicker3.Value.ToShortDateString & ""
        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand
        Dim odpt As New OleDbDataAdapter
        Dim tbl As New DataTable
        With cmd
            .CommandText = OOL
            .Connection = connection
        End With
        With odpt
            .SelectCommand = cmd
            .Fill(tbl)
        End With
        DataGridView4.Rows.Clear()
        For i = 0 To tbl.Rows.Count - 1
            With DataGridView4
                .Rows.Add(tbl.Rows(i)("DIN"), tbl.Rows(i)("clock"), tbl.Rows(i)("JustDate"), tbl.Rows(i)("JustTime"))
            End With
        Next
        connection.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

ex.exception gave me this:
[image: error img]

***When i try to retrieve all the date/time column and the result shows me:***

```
 Dim OOL As String = "SELECT Glogtbl.DIN, Glogtbl.clock, Int([clock]) AS JustDate, [clock]-Int([clock]) AS JustTime FROM Glogtbl"
```

[image: Result after JustDate and JustTime]

The JustDate value still remain format long datetime value. therefore the values going to do comparison with datetimepicker.value become always wrong. End up with retrieve nothing!!!

***Who can guide me on this?!***

Answer (score 0):

Don't use string concatenation to insert values into SQL code.  Always use parameters.  Doing so will avoid issues like incorrect delimiters or formatting, both of which you are experiencing.  E.g.

```
myCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MyColumn = @MyColumn"
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MyColumn", myValue)
```

There are lots of places that you can find more information on ADO.NET parameters, e.g.

http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com.au/2009/08/using-parameters-in-adonet.html